# Parallel task, while using ContinueWith, result of first action is not finding

Tags: c#

I am  new to TPL , so just going through some of Tutorials  of  regarding the same , 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Here in above Link  i am  trying to Use This Code

```
 var displayData = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
                                         Random rnd = new Random(); 
                                         int[] values = new int[100];
                                         for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= values.GetUpperBound(0); ctr++)
                                            values[ctr] = rnd.Next();

                                         return values;
                                      } ).  
                ContinueWith((x) => {
                                int n = x.Result.Length;
                                long sum = 0;
                                double mean;

                                for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= x.Result.GetUpperBound(0); ctr++)
                                   sum += x.Result[ctr];

                                mean = sum / (double) n;
                                return Tuple.Create(n, sum, mean);
                             } ). 
                ContinueWith((x) => {
                                return String.Format("N={0:N0}, Total = {1:N0}, Mean = {2:N2}",
                                                     x.Result.Item1, x.Result.Item2, 
                                                     x.Result.Item3);
                             } );
```

I am Replacing above code With Mine

```
 var taskList = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                var newRandom = new Random();
                var intArray = new int[100];
                Console.WriteLine("Begining  of First  Iteration");
                Parallel.For(0, intArray.GetUpperBound(0) - 1, i =>
                {
                    intArray[i] = newRandom.Next();
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                });
                Console.WriteLine("End of First Iteration");

            }).ContinueWith((x) => {
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning of Second  Iteration");
                int n = x.Result.Length;
                long sum = 0;
                double mean;

                for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= x.Result.GetUpperBound(0); ctr++)
                    sum += x.Result[ctr];

                mean = sum / (double)n;
                Console.WriteLine("End of  Second Iteration");
                return Tuple.Create(n, sum, mean);
                });
```

I am getting the Error ::

```
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It not finding  the "Result"

What  i am doing wrong ??

Comment: Your first task doesn't return anything.. review your code before ContinueWith... your version has no return statement.

Comment: @@Simon  Thanks , i got the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task` class does not have a `Result` property, `Task<T>` does.

The problem is, your delegate in the `StartNew` does not return a value, so it resolves to returning a `Task` instead of `Task<T>`.

Try adding this:

```
...
Console.WriteLine("End of First Iteration");
return intArray;
```